# Amount credit vs Amount debit?

Tags: banking

I'm an expat that recently moved to Germany. Immediately after relocating, I opened a Deutsche Bank account and received a Master Card and Maestro Card + access to my e-banking portal.

However, I noticed that on the portal there are two rows which state:

Amount credit   9999.99 (some example sum)  EUR

Amount debit    0,00        EUR

Can someone explain what's the difference between the two? How can I add money to the debit card? Also, why if I pay with my Master Card, I don't see the changes reflected on the e-banking portal?

Comment: Would it be possible to post a screen shot with the personal details and amounts blacked out?